Deriving Graded-Anticommutativity of the $\wedge$ from the following abstract definition.
I am studying differential forms at present and I have been reading from Frank W Warner's book on Differentiable Manifolds and Lie groups.In this book,the author has defined the Exterior Algebra of a vector space $V$ using the following route:
Let $C(V)=\bigoplus\limits_{k\geq 0} V_{k,0}$ which is a subalgebra of $T(V)=\bigoplus\limits_{r,s\geq 0}V_{r,s}$,the Tensor algebra of $V$.Let $I(V) $ be the $2$ sided ideal of $C(V)$ generated by elements of the form $v\otimes v$ for $v\in V$.
Let $I_k(V)=I(V)\cap V_{k,0}$ .Then $I(V)=\bigoplus\limits_{k\geq 0} I_k(V)$.We can show that $I(V)$ is a graded ideal of $C(V)$ and define the exterior algebra $\Lambda(V)$ of $V$ to be the graded quotient algebra $C(V)/I(V)$.If we set $\Lambda_k(V)=V_{k,0}/I_k(V)$ for $k\geq 2$ and $\Lambda_0(V)=\mathbb R$ and $\Lambda_1(V)=V$,then we can write $\Lambda(V)=\bigoplus\limits_{k\geq 0}\Lambda_k(V)$ and we denote the multiplication in $\Lambda(V)$ by $\wedge$ which is called the wedge product or the exterior product.
Using the above definition,I am supposed to show the following:
If $u\in \Lambda_k(V)$ and $v\in \Lambda_l(V)$,then $u\wedge v\in \Lambda_{k+l}(V)$ and $u\wedge v=(-1)^{kl} (v\wedge u)$.
If we could think of $\Lambda(V)$ as an alternating tensor algebra,then showing the above would be trivially easy.But here I am supposed to use the above definition which means that I have to think of $u\wedge v$ as the residue class of $u\otimes v$ modulo the ideal $I(V)$.
I am unable to figure out how exactly I should proceed with proving the above result directly from the definition I have.
Can anyone here come up with some suggestions that might help?
Thanks in advance.

All you need to show is that $u\wedge v = -v\wedge u$. Then it suffices to prove the claim using this fact on simple multivectors $v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_k$ because the projection $T(V) \to \Lambda(V)$ is surjective and entirely determined by its action on simple tensors $v_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes v_k \mapsto v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_k$.
